# ERR_CACHE_MISS error on multiple machines (OSX and Windows)

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I'm getting an error across a couple machines at times when I try to connect to the internet via Chrome.

I type the address in, the browser says "Unable to connect to the internet", and in the console, one error and one warning:

The error is: `ERR_CACHE_MISS`

The warning is: `i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph"`

Do these have something to do with why I'm unable to connect? My internet connection is working fine when this happens. Sometimes changing my DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 fixes the problem, sometimes it doesn't.

This issue is coming up for me on both my mac on OSX and my PC on Windows 7.

Chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.99 m

It isn't on specific sites that I can tell - just at seemingly specific times. I do have plugins installed, and was thinking that possibly it's a plugin issue, or potentially an issue with a plugin that I uninstalled but didn't uninstall completely (I'm thinking AdBlock Plus...is there a way to fully delete that?).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but as a tip you might want to know that i18n stands for "Internationalization". So it seems something is wrong with the configuration of Chrome, regarding languages.